# Zip and UnZip a folder command line

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, unzip

How to Zip and Unzip a folder using the command line? I don't need to use another tool like 7zip or winrar. Is there a way to use windows zip method using the command line?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into windows for that at least, MS provides no executable for it, however you can take a look at something like [Power-shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Power-shell can do something like this;

```
Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory('foo', 'foo.zip')
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', 'bar')
```

If you search on stack-overflow a little you can find a lot more posts about this.

Hier are also some other posts about this subject that can be of help; 
[Link Post 1](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili) 
[Link Post 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line)